# While executing my project in angular6 its executing only index.html page only, what are the reasons?

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular6

I had created one project for login form, here am attaching screenshot of program, 
[image: login form screenshot]

while am executing my project it is showing only index page and waited for some time but still showing only index page, here am attaching output screenshot,

[image: output screen shot]

Comment: What do you want to display instead index page? Login page?

Comment: username and password fields with login button,and registration page link .

Comment: I have added an answer with step to follow check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a login page as a default page when user serves the application then you have to configure your `app.module.ts` to handle these type of URL. So the changes that you required is as:

In `app.module.ts`:

Import `RouterModule` from `angular/router`:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

and in imports Array add

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
])
```

and in app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: it's not working,still it is showing only index page.

Comment: @Harshi check my updated answer! Have added a path for Login Component in forRoot array

Comment: Pimaple it is working now. thanks for ur help with patience.

Answer (score 0):

That’s because when we run ng-serve to start up our server it creates JavaScript bundles and automatically adds the right imports into our index.html.

In order for your app.component.html to show in `localhost:4200`, add `<router-outlet></router-outlet?` to your index.html.